# using taylor's theorem

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

using Taylor's theorem . I need to find $f\left ( x \right ) = \frac{x^{2}+1}{x^{2}-2x+1}$ when $a=0$ and (the variable): $k=n$

I tried to use the taylor's theorem on $g\left ( x \right ) = \frac{1}{(x-1)^{2}}$

and i came to this result $f\left ( x \right ) =2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left (n+1  \right )x^{n}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left (n+1  \right )x^{2}+\epsilon (x^{n})$ is it correct ?

thanks for your support.

Comment: $\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^2$ makes no sense.

Comment: What are $\;a,\,k\;$ in your question?

Comment: What do you mean $\;\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty (n+1)x^2=x^2\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty (n+1)\;$ ? This series obviously diverges for any $\;x\neq0\;$ ...

Comment: @SimpleArt iv' just edited i forgot to add that $(n+1)$

Comment: @DonAntonio how did u came to that conclusion ?

Comment: @AymanErroutabi Studying. A necessary condition for a series to converge is that the general term sequence converges to zero...right? What you wrote there makes no sense.

Comment: @DonAntonio I see. bad start i guess thanks for clarifying .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More quickly note that

$$g(x)=\frac d{dx}\frac1{1-x}=\frac d{dx}\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(n+1)x^n$$

Multiply it by $x^2+1$ and you should've got

$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(n+1)x^{n+2}+\sum_{k=0}^\infty(k+1)x^k\\=1+2x+\sum_{n=2}^\infty(n-1)x^n+\sum_{k=2}^\infty(k+1)x^k\\=1+2x+2\sum_{n=2}^\infty nx^n$$

> $$f(x)=1+2\sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^n$$

Comment: You re correct tried it with Taylor's theorem and with @E.H.E 's hint it worked thanks man

Comment: @AymanErroutabi Sure :D

Answer (score 2):

Hint:
$$f\left ( x \right ) = \frac{x^{2}+1}{x^{2}-2x+1}=1+\frac{2}{(x-1)}+\frac{2}{(x-1)^2}$$

Comment: Thanks man it worked like a charm . same result as @SimpleArt 's one